# How to create junctions in win7 with gui?

Tags: windows-7, gui

Is there a possibilty to create junctions(symbolic links) with the graphical user interface, instead of using the console with mklink /J ?

I did it on Win8.1(professional?), but I don't remember well how.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

#### How can I create junctions(symbolic links) with the graphical user interface?

You can use [Link Shell Extension](http://schinagl.priv.at/nt/hardlinkshellext/linkshellextension.html):

> Link Shell Extension (LSE) provides for the creation of Hardlinks ,
> Junctions , Volume Mountpoints , and Windows7/8's Symbolic Links,
> (herein referred to collectively as Links), a folder cloning process
> that utilises Hardlinks or Symbolic Links and a copy process taking
> care of Junctions, Symbolic Links, and Hardlinks.
>
> LSE, as its name implies is implemented as a Shell extension and is
> accessed from Windows Explorer, or similar file/folder managers.
>
> The extension allows the user to select one or many files or folders,
> then using the mouse, complete the creation of the required Links -
> Hardlinks, Junctions or Symbolic Links or in the case of folders to
> create Clones consisting of Hard or Symbolic Links.
>
> LSE is supported on all Windows versions that support NTFS version 5.0
> or later, including Windows XP64 and Windows7/8/10.  Hardlinks,
> Junctions and Symbolic Links are NOT supported on FAT file systems,
> and nor is the Cloning and Smart Copy process supported on FAT file
> systems.

...

> Since LSE supports Junction, Clones and with Windows7/8/10 Symbolic
> Links, when one or more folders are selected as the Source Links they
> can be dropped in several forms.
>
> To avoid crowding the popup menu, a submenu is provided that contains
> the different types of Links applicable to folders.
>
> [image]

Comment: Thats a useful app, thanks. On win8 I created the junctions it was not needed, perhaps it was an enterprise edition.